# QGIS 3.34.1 problem during the creation of a grid

Tags: qgis

[image]I try to use the tool for the creation of a grid, but the unit for the horizontal and vertical spacing is degrees and not meters. How to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Do you mean in print layout?

Comment: reproject your layer, I suspect it is EPSG:4326, is not it?

Comment: "I try to use the tool". Which tool? Consider adding a screenshot - it makes many questions much clearer.

Comment: Hi, see my new post, with the image of the issue !

Comment: No need to reproject any layer, just set the project CRS  (temporarily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should change your proyection in your QGIS proyect. I found this [tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=CHANGE%20PROYECTION%20PROYECT%20QGIS&rlz=1C1FHFK_esES998ES998&oq=CHANGE%20PROYECTION%20PROYECT%20QGIS&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQg2NTAyajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:c04380de,vid:OmPH1es1w1k,st:0). You should select a projection with meters as units.

Remember to also change your projection in the tool you are using.

[image]